# ValueError: No route found for path 'ws/chat/AUdZzo8slKKwKvzmUrnmLRfnVkuAYfJj/'

Tags: javascript, python, django, websocket, daphne

I am working on a django chatting application that uses websockets to carry out its chatting functionality.
I am getting the following error in daphne:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/gamedeveloper/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/channels/routing.py", line 62, in __call__
    return await application(scope, receive, send)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/gamedeveloper/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/channels/routing.py", line 62, in __call__
    return await application(scope, receive, send)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/gamedeveloper/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/channels/routing.py", line 134, in __call__
    raise ValueError("No route found for path %r." % path)
ValueError: No route found for path 'ws/chat/AUdZzo8slKKwKvzmUrnmLRfnVkuAYfJj/'.
```

I ran the following daphne command using ubuntu on my remote server:

```
(venv) gamedeveloper@animechatapp:~/anime_chat/anime_chat_app$ daphne -u /tmp/daphne.sock --bind my.ip.address -p 8001 anime_chat_app.asgi:application
```

I figured that there might be some issues with my firewall settings on my remote server so I made some changes and allowed traffic on port 8001 but I am still getting the error.

The following is the JS code I am using to establish connection with the websocket:

```
const chatSocket = new WebSocket(
    (window.location.protocol === 'https:' ? 'wss://' : 'ws://') +
    window.location.host +
    '/ws//chat/' +
    roomName +
    '/'
);
```

The following is the output inside my console window

```
WebSocket connection to 'ws://194.195.119.237/ws/chat/AUdZzo8slKKwKvzmUrnmLRfnVkuAYfJj/' failed:
```

The following is routing.py:

```
from django.urls import re_path
from . import consumers

websocket_urlpatterns = [
    re_path(r'^ws://chat/(?P<room_name>\w+)/$', consumers.ChatRoomConsumer.as_asgi())
]
```

The following is consumers.py (although I am pretty sure there is no error here):

```
from channels.generic.websocket import AsyncWebsocketConsumer
import json
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
# from channels.db import database_sync_to_async
from asgiref.sync import sync_to_async
from .models import ChatRoom, Message, Profile
from asyncer import asyncify

@sync_to_async
def save_message_to_database(chatroom_name, username, message):
    try:
        chatroom = ChatRoom.objects.get(name=chatroom_name)
        user = User.objects.get(username=username)
        user_profile = Profile.objects.get(user=user)

        new_message = Message.objects.create(chat_room=chatroom, sender=user_profile, content=message)
        print("Message saved to DB:", new_message)

    except ChatRoom.DoesNotExist:
        print(f"Chatroom with name '{chatroom_name}' does not exist.")
   
    except Profile.DoesNotExist:
        print(f"User profile with username '{username}' does not exist.")

    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Error occurred while saving the message: {e}")
@sync_to_async
def get_chatroom_by_name(name):
    try:
        return ChatRoom.objects.get(name=name)
    except ChatRoom.DoesNotExist:
        return None
@sync_to_async
def get_messages_for_chatroom(chatroom):
    return list(Message.objects.filter(chat_room=chatroom).order_by('timestamp'))

class ChatRoomConsumer(AsyncWebsocketConsumer):
    async def connect(self):
        self.room_name = self.scope['url_route']['kwargs']['room_name']
        self.room_group_name = 'chat_%s' % self.room_name
        await self.channel_layer.group_add(
            self.room_group_name,
            self.channel_name
        )
       
        await self.accept()
        print("Before getting chatroom")
        chatroom = await get_chatroom_by_name(self.room_name)
       
        print("chatroom:",chatroom)
   
        print("Chatroom:",chatroom)
        messages = await get_messages_for_chatroom(chatroom.id)
        for message in messages:
            print("SENDING MESSAGE TO FUNCTION")
            await self.send_message_to_client(message)
       


    async def send_message_to_client(self, message):
        user_id = await sync_to_async(lambda: message.sender.user_id)()
        user = await sync_to_async(lambda: User.objects.get(id=user_id))()
        print("SENDING MESSAGES TO THE FRONTEND")
        await self.send(text_data=json.dumps({
            'message': message.content,
            'username': user.username,
            'user_pfp': message.sender.profile_picture.url,
            'room_name': self.room_name,
        }))
   
    async def disconnect(self, close_code):
        await self.channel_layer.group_discard(
            self.room_group_name,
            self.channel_name
        )

    async def receive(self, text_data):
        text_data_json = json.loads(text_data)
        message = text_data_json['message']
        username = text_data_json['username']
        user_pfp = text_data_json['user_pfp']
        room_name = text_data_json['room_name']

        await save_message_to_database(chatroom_name=room_name, username=username, message=message)

        await self.channel_layer.group_send(
            self.room_group_name,
            {
                'type': 'chatroom_message',
                'message': message,
                'username': username,
                'user_pfp': user_pfp,
                'room_name': room_name,
                'tester_message': 'tester message in receive function'
            }
        )

    async def chatroom_message(self, event):
        message = event['message']
        username = event['username']
        user_pfp = event['user_pfp']

        await self.send(text_data=json.dumps({
            'message': message,
            'username': username,
            'user_pfp': user_pfp,
            'tester_message': 'tester message in chatroom message'
        }))
```

Please help me out with this problem!